# Apache spark on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, apache-spark

The question I asked was marked as too broad. After searching around more I got my basics more clear. So hopefully I will be much more specific now.
Basically I was trying to run the sample examples given on eclipse rather than on terminal. My first doubt has already been answered correctly. Using setMaster("local"). I got the example running n it displayed output quite correctly. Now if I change this to  setMaster("yarn-client") now it connects to yarn, also submits the job then runs it but finally I get classnotfoundexception and hence reduce not completed. If I want to use yarn-client do I need to add some extra specification for my class so that I don't get classnotfoundexception. For this entire process I used the inbuilt JavaPiSpark example program in my version of spark. Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: can you please provide the steps in setting up eclipse to run your spark project? I'm new to this whole thing and it's mind boggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `JavaSparkContext .setMaster("local")` to run on your local machine or replace the "local" with a specific master URL to run on clusters.

Please refer [spark programming guide - initializing-spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#initializing-spark) and [master-urls](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls)

Comment: Thanx ur answer allowed me to get the example running on local. So I will mark it correct as per my orginal question. I have also edited my question now so as to be more specific as I can

Comment: You need a specific URL of clusters master node to run on clusters. Like `.setMaster("spark://ec2-12-123-12-123.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077")`.